# Can't seem to find Sycamore after Elite Four in Pokemon X

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In the end game of Pokemon X, Professor Sycamore told me to meet him in Lumiose city but I can't find him anywhere.

Comment: Isn't he at his lab?

Comment: @NolanNite Note that you can (and should) mark an answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark below the answer's score. This will reward both you and the answerer with reputation, place the answer topmost even if other answers are added and mark the question itself as answered so others know it's been taken care of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you first defeat the Elite Four, your mother tells you that Prof. Sycamore wants to meet you at Lumiose Station in Lumiose City.  [As seen on this map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnE9m.jpg), Lumiose Station is located at the east end of North Boulevard, south of the Route 16 gate and the Battle Institute.  If you have trouble finding it, you can take any cab in Lumiose to get there (Select "Transportation" at the first menu).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the route 16 gate in Lumiose City, turn around and then go left and the station will be right there. The two lab assistants will give you the national pokedex and the go talk to Sycamore and he will give you the TMV pass.

Answer (score -1):

You take a taxi to The gate of route 16 then follow the path

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers.